# Admobs ADs missing in PhoneGap InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova, admob, inappbrowser

I'm building a Android application using jQuery Mobile and PhoneGap. I incorporated admob into the project using the phonegap admob plugin from Github. In my project, I open external links using PhoneGap's InAppBrowser feature. My ADs show up well in the App at the bottom of the screen, however upon clicking an external link in the App and the InAppBrowser window appears...the ads disappear. But when I'm done with the external link in the InAppBrowser window and then go back to the main App view, the ADs show up normally. What's the best way to fix this please? I'm using PhoneGap 2.9

Comment: wow! 2 days, not one single response. Does it mean no solution for this?

Comment: did you get the solutio for this?